# Find all node predecessors in a directed graph

Tags: python, pandas, graph, networkx, graph-theory

I need to find all the connected elements in column ID.

for e.g. My main Element is `4120882840` in `ID` Column.

`4120882840`  is connected to `4120874920, 4120874720` (refer column `ID2`)
likewise, `4120874920` is connected to `4121482000` which is further connected to `4121480930` and so on

finally, all the elements that are connected to `4120882840` are `[4120882840, 4120874920, 4121482000, 4121480930, 4121480780, 4120874720, 4120871840, 4120871830]` total 8 in the list

But I am only getting first 7 i.e. `[4120882840, 4120874920, 4121482000, 4121480930, 4121480780, 4120874720, 4120871840]`

file link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E5_cbGjtKoB6RDSsC7ned-X2RFoF6Rad/view?usp=sharing

This is my Code

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("Test.csv")
ID = df.iloc[:,1] 
ID2 = df.iloc[:,2] 

x = [4120882840]
for i in range (len(ID)):
    for element in x:
        if element == ID2[i]:
            newID = ID[i]
            #print (newID)
            x.append (newID)
print (x)
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to find all [predecessors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_graph_theory_terms#predecessor) of the node in question. This becomes clearer by inspecting the corresponding component subgraph:

```
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='ID', target='ID2',
                                create_using=nx.DiGraph)

comps = nx.weakly_connected_components(G)
comp = next(comp for comp in comps if 4120882840 in comp)
H = nx.subgraph(G, comp)
plt.figure(figsize=(10,4))
nx.draw(H, node_color='lightgreen', with_labels=True, node_size=500)
```

[image]

We can use  to find the node's predecessors. NetworkX has [`nx.edge_dfs`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.traversal.edgedfs.edge_dfs.html), where we can set `orientation='reverse'` to traverse every predecessor edge in reverse order (*upstream*). Then we can just flatten the returned list of tuples to obtain the corresponding nodes:

```
from itertools import chain 
source = 4120882840

*n, _ = zip(*(nx.edge_dfs(G, source, orientation='reverse')))
print(set(chain.from_iterable(n)))
{4120874720, 4120871840, 4121480930, 4120874920, 4121480780, 
 4121482000, 4120871830, 4120882840}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```py
import networkx as nx
graph = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='ID', target='ID2',
                                create_using=nx.DiGraph)
visited = set()
to_visit = [4120882840]
while to_visit:
    dst = to_visit.pop()
    visited.add(dst)
    for parent in graph.predecessors(dst):
        if parent in visited:
            continue
        to_visit.append(parent)
print(visited)
```

Output

```
{4120874720, 4120871840, 4121480930, 4120874920, 4121480780, 4121482000, 4120871830, 4120882840}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use mask to check if the element in `ID2` and you can use `list(set(x))` to remove duplicate

Here is an algorithm that work:

```
x = [4120882840]
lastLen = 0
while lastLen != len(x):
    lastLen = len(x)
    for i in x:
        x += list(df['ID'][df['ID2'] == i])
        x = list(set(x))
```